# Using TensorFlow to optimize a graph over a moving time series data window without dict_feed

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to set up an optimization graph in Tensorflow that avoids using `feed_dict` with a `tf.FIFOQueue` - at least this seems to be the right direction for time series data.

I will first describe how my graph looks (in minimal terms) using `feed_dict`, and then where I am trying to take it.

Let's say my time series is stored in a numpy array `time_series`:

```
wnd = 10 # window size
data_wnd = np.array([time_series[n:n+wnd] for n in range(1,time_series.size()+1)])
```

Now `data_wnd[k]` can represent window `k` in the time series.

Assuming `step` is my Tensorflow optimizier, this would work classically as follows:

```
for k in range(data_wnd.shape[0]):
    for n in range(epochs):
        sess.run(step, feed_dict={data_:data_wnd[k]})
    # Do stuff after optimization and proceed to next window frame
    # the optimized variable values for this frame are the initial values for the next frame
```

If I didn't have a window, then instead of using a placeholder `data_` I could simply use a `tf.constant` and be rid of `feed_dict`. So that is out of the question.

So in comes `tf.FIFOQueue`:

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=5, shapes=(wnd))
nq_op = q.enqueue(data_wnd[0])
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(q, [nq_op]*1) # nq_op is not right
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)
data_ = q.dequeue() # instead of a placeholder
```

Great, so now I have a queue, but this is clearly wrong. `qr` needs to feed the correct data frame into the queue depending on `k`. Is there a way to get either `enqueue` or `QueueRunner` to select the correct frame?

Better yet, is there some specialized Tensorflow API to deal with time-series data in this fashion?

An important constraint to the solution requires that I keep everything in the same session and variables are not reinitialized because the optimized solution of a frame is close to the optimal solution of the previous frame.

**An incomplete proposal**

I was thinking of having several `nq_op` defined as follows:

```
nq_op = []
for k in range(data_wnd.shape[0]):
    nq_op = np.append(nq_op, q.enqueue(data_wnd[0]))
```

But this still leaves the need for `QueueRunner` to correctly select the right `enqueue`.

**Another proposal**

Apparently Tensorflow now has a `tf.data` API, but I have no idea where to start - or for that matter, end - with this API.

Comment: Hi! Can I ask why you want to get rid of feed_dict? I have implemented CNN for acceleration (time series data) with feed_dict using batches.

Comment: Apparently, feed_dict is less efficient than using a buffer in this way because of how python/tensorflow fetches data. I don't know the full details - which you can read about here: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide

But I can see this making sense. Firstly, I can see my python script utilizing less of the cpu/gpu as its RAM utilization increases - utilization eventually drops by more than half. Secondly, I tried posting a "simple" version, but in a situation where you are feeding a lot of mostly static data, it might be better to use some buffer, like the queue.

Comment: To add and summarize, I think the key here is that `feed_dict` is simply a sequential process between fetching the data and using it, while queueing allows you to separate the task of fetching and using the data across multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that FIFOQueue is not the right direction for this.

Instead, [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) offers the right method under **Preloaded Data**.

Instead of simply using a placeholder, we can use a combination of placeholder and Variable for `data_`:

```
data_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, data_wnd.shape[0])
data_ = tf.Variable(data_init, trainable=False, collection=0)
```

Where `VarType` and `TensorShape` are defined appropriately.

Then in our loops:

```
for k in range(data_wnd.shape[0]):
    sess.run(data_.initializer, feed_dict={data_:data_wnd[k]})
    for n in range(epochs):
        sess.run(step)
```

Notice how we no longer need to feed the data for each `n`, but only when we moved the window forward.

Comment: After several tests, it seems that the cpu/gpu are working 50%-100% harder. There is also a significant decrease in the step times.